# Need some general classes advice

Tags: swift, oop

I appreciate this is not Swift specific, but I am writing a small game in Swift thus I have tagged it with the relevant tag. I am new to the Swift language but picking it up quickly, and while not new to programming in general, do often question my approaches.

Here is my scenario:

I am writing a small 2D platform game with a player character and various obstacles. The player can have different textures but generally shares the same capabilities, such as jump and sprint. Likewise, the obstacles generally have different textures, but otherwise share the same capabilities.

Both the characters and obstacles also share common capabilities but not all, for example an obstacle can't jump. With this in mind, this is how I have written my classes...

```
class GameObject {

  let node : SKSpriteNode!

}

Class GameObstacle: GameObject {

  init() {
    super.init()
  }

  func explode() {
    // explode code
  }

}

class GameCharacter: GameObject {

  init() {
    super.init()
  }

  func jump() {
    // jump code
  }

}

class GameCharacter_Sheep : GameCharacter {

  init() {
    super.init()
    self.node = SKSpriteNode(namedFile: "sheep")
  }

}
```

My logic behind this approach is that all of the common object functionality is included in the GameObject class, all of the common character functionality (such as jump) is included in the character class and the unique stuff, down at the class level.

One question I have, am I correct to initialize my node (defined in my GameObject class) in my GameCharacter_Sheep class? My rationale is that because the texture, and thus physics body will differ from character to character, that is the correct place to do the implementation?

Again, I appreciate that this may be basic OOP and not really Swift specific but I'm just looking for some guidance.

Many Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

If all your game objects are going to have an instance of `SKSpriteNode` which is passed data from a named file, you can move it's creation into the base class, and just have the file named passed into the call to `super.init()`.

More generally, **inheritance** isn't the only option for sharing functionality between different game objects. Don't forget about **composition**, which is often preferred when defining game objects to avoid deep, inflexible inheritance hierarchies which sometimes cannot model the desired behaviour. There are a whole bunch of ways to approach all the way through to a full blown game object component based system.